# How to experimentally determine the degree of atomization of the propellants mixing in a fuel injector?

Tags: rockets, liquid-fuel, testing, experiment, injector

When validating a fuel injector design on a test stand using liquid water to simulate a liquid-liquid fuel injector(the one i'm working with currently is a pintle design but I suppose one could theoretically use any fuel injector design they would like to validate) what is the best way to determine the degree of atomization of the propellants?

Comment: What is the target range for the size of the atomized particles? There are several different ways possible at least in theory, and their applicability will depend on droplet size.

Comment: Although no doubt convenient, how accurately will the behaviour of water mimic that of rocket propellant which I suspect will be non-polar?

Answer (score -1):

One can work this one backwards, by evaluating the flame.

Degree of atomization will depend on pressure, flow rate, and orifice design.

But the chemical properties of what one is atomizing are critical, which is why *water* is a poor choice.

Boiling point and expected temperature of atomization chamber may show what one is injecting simply turns to gas (moleculization?).
You can't get any better than that (maybe with optimized mixing), but it will increase uncontrolled combustion (detonation) risks.

Surface tension (how much the liquid wants to stick to itself) is particularly high in water (because each H2O has a positive and negative end), but nearly absent in hydrocarbons.

So, for example, if you compared equal amounts methane, gasoline, and diesel at room temperature, you will see a difference in their flame.  These differences might be much less at higher temperatures, with increased oxygen content, or with better physical atomization.

Comment: this doesn't really describe how to measure it or calculate it without just all-out testing a fully manufactured engine

Comment: Or a "test stand" as above.  Degree of atomization could be measured by engine performance, but it is critical to mimic the environment the fuel is intended to be injected into in real use.